# Dual boot Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows 8

Tags: 13.04, windows-8

I need help with booting Ubuntu on my windows 8 laptop.  I got the iso image extracted onto a DVD.  What next?  I already tried Easy BCD 2.2 and it did not help!  I also tried a you tube video, and that did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Burn/make Your Bootable CD/USB and then boot off of them :)

Then Click Install Ubuntu And FOllow Up Adn If it Says Install Windows Alongside Ubuntu Just Click On that

If the Option is not available click Something Else adn then shrink your Main Partition and instlal ubuntu there

grub Will configure itself And at each boot you will be able to chose what you want to boot

If this answered your question click answered :)

Comment: Help! I thought I did make my cd bootable, however I can not boot off it.  Please answer!

Comment: What Computer make do you have and what model?